# How do I use OpenSSL 1.1.1 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, openssl, 22.04

I understand that Ubuntu 22.04 upgraded to OpenSSL 3.0. This has broken my university's secure WiFi access point joining script because "some insecure algorithms have been disabled by default". I don't want to downgrade to version 1.1.1, but instead install 1.1.1 alongside 3.0 ideally under an alias like `openssl1` (just as I can with e.g. `python2` and `python3`) and then hack the script to use `openssl1`.

What's the closest thing to a supported way to do this?

Comment: I had the same issue with a monitoring tool (falcon-sensor) from the company which I work. Following the ubuntu steps in [this tutorial](https://linuxpip.org/install-openssl-linux/) did the trick for me.

Comment: I found the solution for this in StackOverflow, and hopefully, will work for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633324/8624381

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I faced similar issue because of openssl 3.x move from 1.1.x., such as errors as:

```sh
VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=CA signature digest algorithm too weak
```

However, I still wanted to use graphical network manager as provided by gnome, so It did as mentioned the trick from Gustavo, then build a new openvpn version with openssl 1.1.1 version:

```sh
# Move to temp folder
cd /tmp

# get dependencies
sudo apt install libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev
```

## OpenSSL

**Updated version reason**: I tried with another Ubuntu 22.04 install, but failed to build the `openssl 1.1.1l` library as I did in the previous version (see below *Old version* section). This time, it failed during the `make test` with an error on the test `80-test_ssl_new`, with the following output: `../test/recipes/80-test_ssl_new.t .................. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)`.
After investigation, it seems that because of the upgrade of `perl` package on Ubuntu 22.04 to 5.34, the `@INC` perl module is missing, due to a security issue.

Anyway, instead of trying to solve this new issue, I simply downloaded the Impish binary instead of trying to build it from scratch:

```sh
# download binary openssl packages from Impish builds
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb

# install downloaded binary packages
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

In such case, you can directly use those old version packages to build the OpenVPN with correct dependencies.

## OpenVPN

Now that OpenSSL is 1.1.1l version, as with 21.10 Impish, I can build an OpenVPN binary using 1.1.1l libraries

```sh
# Get OpenVPN sources from Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/openvpn/2.5.5-1ubuntu3/openvpn_2.5.5.orig.tar.xz

# Extract files
tar -xvf openvpn_2.5.5.orig.tar.xz

# build openvpn 2.5.5
cd ..
cd openvpn-2.5.5/
./configure
make -j 4 && sudo make install

# refresh cache
hash -r

# check version
/usr/local/sbin/openvpn --version
ldd /usr/bin/openssl
ldd /usr/local/sbin/openvpn
```

At this stage, I was able to connect to my VPN using existing certificates, however, the graphical network manager was still using the default 2.5.5 OpenVPN version based on OpenSSL 3.x.

## Gnome

I found that the network manager was always targeting binary in `/usr/sbin`, so I made a backup then symlink the built OpenVPN:

```sh
# make a backup of default OpenVPN 2.5.5 before replace
sudo mv /usr/sbin/openvpn /usr/sbin/openvpn-2.5.5_default

# Symlink new OpenVPN client built with OpenSSL 1.1.1l library
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/openvpn /usr/sbin/openvpn
```

## Clean up

If you used the OpenSSL binary from Impish, you should now do a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to recover the newest version of this package.
It should not break your brand *old* OpenVPN version

## Old version of this article

#### OpenSSL

this is the **old version** of the OpenSsl part above:

```sh
# Get OpenSSL sources from Ubuntu 21.10 Impish
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/openssl/1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.6/openssl_1.1.1l.orig.tar.gz

# Extract files
tar -xvf openssl_1.1.1l.orig.tar.gz

# build openssl 1.1.1l
cd /tmp/openssl-1.1.1l/
./config shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib --prefix=/usr/local/ssl
make -j 4
make test && sudo make install

# refresh cache
hash -r

# check version
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl <<< version

# symlink binary for path resolution
sudo ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

#### OpenVPN

This is the **old version** of the OpenVPN part above.
Now that OpenSSL is 1.1.1l version, as with 21.10 Impish, I can build an OpenVPN binary using 1.1.1l libraries

```sh
# Get OpenVPN sources from Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/openvpn/2.5.5-1ubuntu3/openvpn_2.5.5.orig.tar.xz

# Extract files
tar -xvf openvpn_2.5.5.orig.tar.xz

# build openvpn 2.5.5
cd ..
cd openvpn-2.5.5/
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/include -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib"
./configure
make -j 4 && sudo make install

# refresh cache
hash -r

# check version
/usr/local/sbin/openvpn --version
ldd /usr/local/bin/openssl
ldd /usr/local/sbin/openvpn
```

Comment: Following your instructions, `apt` cannot find `libam0g-dev` package

Comment: Download links have changed - 

# download binary openssl packages from Impish builds
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb



Note: This may change in the future

Comment: changed already, look them up here:

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/

Comment: For me, `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` did update libssl-dev and openssl thereby removing the old versions that I had installed. I needed to use `sudo apt-mark hold openssl libssl-dev`.

Answer (score 4):

Building from source works, especially if you can point whatever needs openssl 1.1.1 to a specific directory with the libraries:

```bash
cd /usr/local/src/
sudo git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git -b OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable openssl-1.1.1m
cd openssl-1.1.1m
sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib
sudo make
sudo make test
sudo make install_sw
```

The directory containing the libraries is now `/usr/local/ssl`

Answer (score 2):

enable legacy providers in the latter version:

https://gist.github.com/rdh27785/97210d439a280063bd768006450c435d

```
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

add or change

```
 # List of providers to load
 [provider_sect]
 default = default_sect
 legacy = legacy_sect 
 [default_sect]
 activate = 1
 [legacy_sect]
 activate = 1
```

then restart relevant services (or reboot)