# Stremio doesn't launch on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: libraries, openssl, 22.04

I did a fresh install of 22.04 and installed Stremio 4.4 (latest vesion). When I try to open the app, I get this error: "error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

How can I fix it? It was running great on 20.04.

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/q/1403837/158442 when it gets an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem also found on Ubuntu 22.04: `stremio_4.4.142-1_amd64.deb` won't run.

I solved it by manually installing the `libssl-1.1` and `libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1` packages:

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine. Please, edit your answer to add "sudo" to the first dpkg command.

Comment: first command didn't work: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found`

Comment: Don't do this. Downgrading libssl3 to libssl1 will likely break a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend running the web version of the streamio in a container.

You can do it this way:

1. Install docker if you don't have it yet ([link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/) to how to do it)
2. Download the docker image.

   ```
   docker pull sleeyax/stremio-streaming-server
   ```
3. Run the container.

   ```
   docker run -p 11470:11470 -v ${PWD}:/root/.stremio-server --name=stremio-streaming-server sleeyax/stremio-streaming-server
   ```
4. Start your web browser and go to localhost:11470

Answer (score 2):

Solution from [here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-stremio-streaming-app-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/#5_Solve_Stremio_error_while_loading_shared_libraries_libcryptoso11):

> If you get another error – *Stremio: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*. Then to solve it, we need to download two more packages manually, here is that.

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.21_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Run update and start the App again, this time you will be able to start it.

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There's a new update to openssl. The command below should work just fine.

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a script to help with this problem:
https://github.com/Kyoro93/stremio-install-ubuntu-22.04

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1235372)

Answer (score 1):

If not working the
Eremita do Cerrado's [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404383/1673242) try this

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.21_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.21_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.6-1_amd64.deb
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is receiving `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found`:

This is because there is probably new update pushed out. Check this page for the most recent version:

http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/

Use it with the `wget` command

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still has stremio not launching issue, i did all above and + i had to install additional package libcrypto.so.1.1 and now it works fine

stremio 4.4.159
ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in several places, until I found the solution, the package is already updated and the following commands should be used (I use Ubuntu 22.04):

```
wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucion definitiva para Ubuntu 22.04:
(*wget http://nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb

*sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.19_amd64.deb)

```
                                                    Gracias
```